# FHA Loan for legal alien

Tags: united-states, mortgage, loans

I'm trying to get approved for a FHA loan and I'm 95% there, was supposed to close in 2 days but we made an extension since we're experiencing some complications.

My family and I applied for residence and basically we're just waiting for the green cards to come in the mail, however immigration gave us employment authorization cards and we have Social security numbers.

From what my mortgage officer told me, the underwriter needs to prove that I can continue working legally and it seems we need to prove that out employment authorization cards can be renewed. But they can't. They're simply vouchers in this period between not having and receiving our green cards.
Our status supposedly is that we're residents already. We need to prove that in some way.

I need some direction since our mortgage officer is working hard to come up with a solution, but unfortunately doesn't have much experience with people in our situation. Our extension is for two more weeks and we need to prove this before then, hopefully the green cards come before then but I don't want to rely solely on that.

Has anyone experienced something similar and can offer some alternative approach that can be looked at.

Comment: Have you checked the status online? If it says approved...?

Comment: https://egov.uscis.gov/casestatus/landing.do to check the status.  (Print what it tells you and send it to mortgage officer).  Also, as an FYI, a traditional mortgage usually costs less than a FHA.  Might be too short to shop around, but for future reference.